# CSS Fluid image issue... Vertical Align & Image not starting at the top of the div

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design

**JS FIDDLE Example**
http://jsfiddle.net/2adv2/

**Update on Vertical Align**

Vertical Align works until the max-width is not reached. When the image width is at max width, and if I resize to increase the window height, the image doesn't shift to the middle of the div, but the div expands.

I am facing 2 issues

1. Vertical align is not happening
2. The image moves down a little from the div and kinda overflows when I resize the window a lot - squishing the webpage vertically.

Tell me why this happens. Also vertical align just wont work.

```
CSS:

#heroimg {
    position:relative;
    top:0%;
    height:auto;
    vertical-align:middle;
    max-height:100%;
    max-width:100%;

}

#hero {
    position:relative;
    top:0%;
    bottom:40%;
    height:40%;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:yellow;
}

HTML:
<div id='hero'><img id="heroimg" src="assets/images/dfb.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: Can you post a link to a test case in jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't use `vertical-align` to vertically center things in containers.

However, you can use `display:table` and `display:table-cell` with `vertical-align:middle` to work as you are expecting.

This requires two wrapping `div` tags around the image that you want to center.

The following illustrates the basic technique:

CSS:

```
#outer-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}
#inner-wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="outer-wrapper">
  <div id="inner-wrapper">
    <img src="image.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

See fiddle with this technique applied to your example: http://jsfiddle.net/2adv2/1/

Answer (score 0):

add max-height to the #hero so the div resizes together with the img

```
#hero {
    position:relative;
    top:0%;
    bottom:40%;
    max-height:40%;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

Comment: Works for me, add a reset to the top of your css: * { padding: 0; margin: 0;}

Comment: Doesnt work. I do have that on my body. This is inside the body element.